# Can I use IIS to host WCF services with transport other than HTTP?

Tags: wcf, iis, wcf-hosting

I've searched and didn't find any question similar, so I'm asking.

Is it possible to use IIS with transport other thna HTTP?

If so, how to configure it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This can be done in IIS7. You have to enable the protocols that you want to use and then just create the appropriate endpoints for your service. Here's an **[example](https://web.archive.org/web/20170416011028/http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Duplex_WCF_Services_Hosted_in_IIS_Using_NetTcp.aspx)** of doing that using net.tcp as the transport.

[image]
<sub>(source: [singingeels.com](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Articles/UserImage.aspx?ImageID=24dd85f6-eec6-4c47-85b1-6f75fed49198))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [singingeels.com](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Articles/UserImage.aspx?ImageID=ea9a7245-742f-48db-859f-73133e8731ca))</sub>

Comment: strictly speaking, this is "WAS" in IIS7 - the Windows Process Activation Service. IIS itself (especially v5.x, v6.x) can host ONLY http.